# Application from Android Studio won't install from signed APK, does installs fine over ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, adb

I'm having a problem with installing my application on my phone, and other phones, from it's APK. When I load the application from Android Studio's run button over ADB, it installs just fine with no issues, but when I generate a signed APK and sideload it onto my device (both debug and release), it throws an error saying "App not installed."

I've genuinely looked everywhere for an answer to this but I can't find anything, has anyone else came across this before?

Here's a video of the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1EbAULdrqs

Here's some info about my app.
It uses ZXing, so therefore it uses the phones camera, and as you can see from the video I've the proper permission declared in the manifest, still though for good measure my manifest is as follows:

```
<manifest package="com.android.tighearnan.frenchsscanner"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.Camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.Camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ScannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Just in case you might think it's over stating the old Camera  in the manifest, I've tried installing it without this and it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes, I face the same issue...But I just uninstall the app and reinstall  the APK and it is installed nicely.

Comment: I've tried that already, I've even cleared the data, uninstalled, rebooted and tried to install the app but nothing!! It's such a pain haha

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, and after confirming that my Android device will run apps outside of google play store, checking the build versions, cheking api versions, generating 2 different keystores(you only need one of course), and generating the signed release apk version, my apk would also not install on my device.

My "fix" was to restart the android device. (And make sure that any versions of the app i had on the device during making of the app were uninstalled from the device)

I hope this helps.